# Unwanted import/export loop in sas enterprise guide

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

My goal is to import a table from excel that, run code to get the new updated line of data from that day, append it to the imported data, then export and overwrite the old excel file.

I have every step working correctly on its own, but I can not get the process flow to run the steps in the correct order. Since I set the export step to output the same excel file as I'm importing, it creates a loop in the SAS EG process flow and starts with the export step. I can't figure out how to either set the import step first or delete the link from the export (the step I want last) to the import.

Comment: How have you set up the links?  Did you just let it go in order, or did you manually (right-click) create them?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a matter of running tasks in a certain order, take a look at [Ordered Lists](http://support.sas.com/kb/26/177.html).